# How to set remember me always true or loggedin in grails?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

How to set once user logged in, whenever user come back and visit a website ,user should be **always logged in** rather than asking for a log in until user clear a cookie.

Config Code :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName='xyz_remember_me'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember=true //if true uses remember me even if no chkbox is in the form
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.tokenValiditySeconds=31*24*60*60
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.parameter='_spring_security_remember_me'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.key='xyzApp' // should be unique per application
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.useSecureCookie=false
```

Gsp Code :

```
<input type='checkbox' class='chk' name='${rememberMeParameter}' id='remember_me' checked='checked'/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<input name="_spring_security_remember_me" type="hidden" value="true"/>
```

have you tried with an actual check box ? you could even default it to be checked

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <input type='checkbox' class='chk' name='_spring_security_remember_me'  id='remember_me'   <g:if test='${hasCookie}'>checked='checked'</g:if>/>
    Remember Me
```